# Is the Chrome FileSystem API only available for Chrome Apps (from Chrome Web Store)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, html5-filesystem

I downloaded the Chrome App samples from https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples and tried running the FileSystem sample.

The code works when installed from Chrome Web Store, but I'm interested to know whether the FileSystem API can be made to work for non-Chrome-app cases. A simple experiment trying loading index.html on localhost served by my local Apache webserver exhibits a failure because chrome.filesystem is undefined.

Is Chrome Filesystem intended only for Chrome Apps (I can see that clues might be in the name of the samples repo and the fact that it uses a manifest.json) or is there a way of making it work for general (non-Chrome-app) web applications?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Chrome Filesystem intended only for Chrome Apps

Yes.

> is there a way of making it work for general (non-Chrome-app) web applications?

No. Normal web applications are subject to many security limitations (because you "install" them by visiting a webpage).

---

> A simple experiment trying loading index.html on localhost served by my local Apache webserver

Loading resources over HTTP can be done using the XMLHttpRequest object. No escalated privileges on the client required.

Comment: note that html5 has also a filesystem api. chrome simply extends it.

Comment: Thanks, Quentin and Zig. @Zig: my understanding is that the Filesystem API is no longer part of the HTML5 spec and that it's likely now that Chrome will be the only browser ever to implement it. See comment at top of this article http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: note that page is from 2013. i doubt thats still true given that both firefox and Edge now support the chrome extensions api.

Comment: Thanks, Zig. This is news to me, actually. (just been looking at https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/08/21/the-future-of-developing-firefox-add-ons/).

 You could be forgiven for thinking that the extensions are the new "spec".

Comment: Actually, there is a web filesystem api v2 spec. http://w3c.github.io/filesystem-api/